# Does HTML5 explicitly allow a <select> without selected <option>?

Tags: html

I've checked with the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and it looks like the following code is acceptable:

```
<select>
    <option>I don't have the 'selected' attribute</option>
</select>
```

Furthermore, all browsers seem to consider the first `<option>` as if it was selected.

But is this behaviour *explicitly* allowed, and documented, in the spec?

I've found a [very old discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/148786-select-element-no-selected-options) that pointed to the HTML4 spec, saying:

> If no OPTION element has the selected attribute set, user agent
>   behavior for choosing which option is initially selected is
>   undefined.

Did this change with HTML5? A pointer to the relevant section of the spec would be appreciated.

Comment: Since when is HTML5 an official W3C-approved spec?

Comment: The code is perfectly valid, your question seem to do more with how various browsers would treat it.

Comment: @Denis, OK, replace *spec* with *WC3 Candidate Recommendation*, but that won't change much the question :)

Comment: @j08691 That's my question indeed, hope that's spec'd!

Comment: @Benjamin: it doesn't look like anything changed... http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element (unsurprisingly...)

Comment: @Denis: Actually, it seems to have been specified in the section for the `select` element, and not the `option` element. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now [explicitly defined by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) to a certain extent:

> If the `multiple` attribute is absent and the element's display size is 1, then whenever there are no `option` elements in the `select` element's list of options that have their selectedness set to true, the user agent must set the selectedness of the first `option` element in the list of options in tree order that is not disabled, if any, to true.

In your given markup, the `multiple` and `size` attributes are absent on the `<select>`, and the only `<option>` element inside it is not disabled and does not have a `selected` attribute explicitly set. For a non-multiple `<select>` element the default display size is 1, and so the above rule must be applied by a browser. Note that this is consistent with current browser behavior, and with good reason.

It still does not appear to specify what a browser should do in the event that there are no enabled `<option>` elements in the given `<select>`, however.